# POST Request Method not working in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

Whenever I try a post request, this is the error I get:

> TypeError at /api/
>
> Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is
>   prohibited. Use project_team.set() instead.
>
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ Django
>   Version:  2.0 Exception Type:     TypeError Exception Value:
>
> Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is
>   prohibited. Use project_team.set() instead.
>
> Exception Location:
>     C:\Users\Siddhesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py
>   in **set**, line 509 Python Executable:
>     C:\Users\Siddhesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.6.3 Python Path:
>
> ['C:\Users\Siddhesh\Desktop\TechForSocial\backend', 
>   'C:\Users\Siddhesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python36.zip',
>   'C:\Users\Siddhesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\Siddhesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib',
>   'C:\Users\Siddhesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36', 
>   'C:\Users\Siddhesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Users\Siddhesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytz-2018.5-py3.6.egg']
>
> Server time:  Mon, 17 Dec 2018 17:57:57

`models.py`:

```
class DummyPeopleModel(models.Model):

     person_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

     def __str__(self):

          return self.person_name


class ActiveProject(models.Model):

     project_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     project_abstract = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     project_paper = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     project_team = models.ManyToManyField(DummyPeopleModel, help_text='Team that works on this Project' )
     project_join_us = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.project_name
```

`serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ActiveProject


class ActiveProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:

        model = ActiveProject
        fields = ('id', 'project_name', 'project_abstract', 'project_paper', 'project_team', 'project_join_us',)

     def create(self, validated_data):
        return ActiveProject.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

`views.py`:

```
class ProjectList(generics.ListAPIView):
     queryset = ActiveProject.objects.all()
     serializer_class = ActiveProjectSerializer

     def post(self, request):

         serializer = ActiveProjectSerializer(data=request.data)
         if serializer.is_valid():
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
         return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class ProjectDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
     queryset = ActiveProject.objects.all()
     serializer_class = ActiveProjectSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

as per [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield), specifying `project_team` as a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)` in the serializer might help (don't set it to `read_only` though)

Comment: 'Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, '
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.

Comment: using `all()` should be ok, i.e. `queryset=DummyPeopleModel .objects.all()`

Comment: Using this now:                                                                                project_team=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=DummyPeopleModel.objects.all(), many=True) 

Still giving same error